# Identify this 80's style retro font

Tags: fonts, font-identification

I saw this image in an article about the Ferrari Testarossa and I liked the font. I tried [myfonts.com](https://www.myfonts.com/) and found a match that is remarkably similar but not exactly the same. Maybe the author also edited the image with Photoshop?

Original:

[image: Original]

Match ([myfonts.com](https://www.myfonts.com/)):

[image: Match]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Yes there's a possibility that it's a font which was modified, or perhaps it's not a font at all - but a custom design. Not everything is a font.

Comment: I think it *is* a font. But I don't think it's an edited version of the Vengeance font. Too many differences. They just follow the same principle but with quite different details in the strokes. I was looking for a similar font once but since I only needed to make one word I ended up drawing it myself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe it is [Fighting Spirit TBS](https://www.1001fonts.com/fighting-spirit-tbs-font.html)

[image: Sample image]

Comment: yes, it was. Accepted